# How can I parse the following xml in c#

Tags: c#, xml

I need some help on how to get values of `English` and `studentId` from this XML. Maybe it needs some special parsing I can't figure out at the moment.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
<processResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <processResult>
    <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <returnedResponse>
            <English>94</English>
            <Remarks>Excellent</Remarks>
            <studentId>tst005</studentId>
            <Department>6</Department>
        </returnedResponse>
    </processResult>
</processResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I have tried the following code:

```
XmlDocument xdr = new XmlDocument();
xdr.LoadXml(thexml);
XmlNodeList nodelist = xdr.SelectNodes("//processResponse/processResult/returnedResponse");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) 
{
    string eng = node.SelectSingleNode("English").InnerText;
    Response.Write("eng");
}
```

Comment: `var thexml="<?xml version="1.0" enc...` The string ends after the = if you declare it like this. You'd have to escape the ". Reading that from a file or stream should work. Next issue is `<processResult>
    <xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` 1. There is a missing "?", 2. you cannot have that inside the xml. I guess you'd want to include the response XML as CDATA and extract that as separate document.

Comment: this line in the middle is not allowed. `<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: there are plenty of good answers - select one

Answer (score 0):

1) XML ist invalid at line 6 ->  because it does not have a closing tag. If you cannot edit the Service and strip the xml header or encode the resulting xml, you have to strip the line 6 in you consumercode.

2) You have to define the Namespaces!

Btw: I highly recommend using (Linq2XML) XDocument. Your code could look like this:

```
XDocument xdr = XDocument.Parse(...);
var nodes = xdr.XPathSelectElements("//*[name()='returnedResponse']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error with invalid XML or does your SelectNodes not find anything?

How about this path

```
XmlNodeList nodelist = xdr.SelectNodes("/*/*/*/processResponse/processResult/returnedResponse");
```

Comment: the xml if returned from the service, throws no error but returns Empty.  But if you copy the xml and use it throws some invalid characters error. I tried your answer but got root element "Missing Error". Thanks for response. is there a way out of this?

Comment: The XML does  look weird, I had to remove some of the lines to make it work, for example the <xml> declaration in the middle, just like Ofir said.

When that line is gone you need to ignore the namespace that is defined in <processedResponse> like this:

    XmlNodeList nodelist = xdr.SelectNodes("/*/*/*[local-name() = 'processResponse']/*[local-name() = 'processResult']/*[local-name() = 'returnedResponse']");

And finally for the SingleNode

    string eng = node.SelectSingleNode("*[local-name() = 'English']").InnerText;

Answer (score 0):

You can try with SelectSingleNode, just like this.

```
var English= xdr.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("English").InnerText;

var studentId = xdr.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("studentId").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
XmlNodeList nList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("returnedResponse");

foreach (XmlNode node in nList)
{
   XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(node.OuterXml);
   var Descendents = xelement.Descendants();
   foreach (var item in Descendents)
   {
     //you'll get each of your descendents here
   }
}
```